# Как преобразовать массив в Стек

Tags: c#

Во первых возможно ли это ?...,

У меня есть `стек` со `строками`, при **выходе** из приложения я создаю массив и сохраняю данные в `PlayerPrefsX.SetStringArray ("listNameSt",listNameFromStack);`. Как мне при запуске приложения создать заного `Стек` из массива.

```
Stack <string> backStack;

public void Start(){
     backStack = new Stack<string> ();
}

//** Запись в стек **//

public void OnApplicationQuit(){
    string[] listNameFromStack = backStack.OrderBy(num => num).ToArray();

    PlayerPrefsX.SetStringArray ("listNameSt",listNameFromStack);
}
```

Comment: А зачем вы сортируете массив?

Comment: Мда спс не догадался что меняются позиций ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В массив:

```
string[] listNameFromStack = backStack.OrderBy(num => num).ToArray();
```

Из массива:

```
backStack = new Stack<string>(listNameFromStack);
```

Comment: Моё решение ситуаций )

`public void Start(){
  arraystack = PlayerPrefsX.GetStringArray ("listNameSt");
  if (arraystack.Length > 0) {
   backStack = new Stack<string> (arraystack);
  } else {
   backStack = new Stack<string> ();
  }
 }`

Comment: Подскажите как решить? Оба ваших ответа правильны, какой указать как решение ))))

Comment: @Abs3akt тот, который наиболее понятно описывает решение

Answer (score 4):

Используйте конструктор стека с `IEnumerable`

```
string[] array = ["a1","a2","a3"];
Stack<string> stack = new Stack<string>(array);
```